# How to solve the problem of attribute error in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make the search bar work. Whenever I type something in `views.py`, it should be appeared and others shouldn't. I have written code which I will show but when I run the code, it gives me attribute error `type object 'Destination' has no attribute 'filter'`. How to solve this problem?

*index.html*

```
<form class="love" method="GET" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder='Search..' name="srh" value="{{request.GET.srh}}"> <br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Search </button>
</form>
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Destination
from django.db.models import Q

def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')
    if query:
        match = Destination.filter(Q(desc_icontains=query))

    # instead of writing this
    target1 = a, b= [Destination() for __ in range(2)]
    a.img = 'Article.jpg'
    b.img = 'Micro Tasks.jpeg'

    a.desc = 'Article Writing'
    b.desc = 'Micro Tasks'

    # I am trying to make a loop but it is not working.
    target1 = Destination.objects.all()
    for field in target1:
        [Destination(img = f'{field.img}', title = f'{field.title}') for __ in range(2)]
```

*app url*

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [path('', views.index, name='index')]
```

*main url*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from firstapp.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('firstapp.urls'))]
```

*Installed apps*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: `Destination.objects.filter`??

Comment: I have updated ```views.py``` Please check someone and answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Destination` class is *not* a model. In order to make something a model, you should make that class a subclass of the [**`Model`** class [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model). Furthermore the fields you want to store in the database should be instances of the [**`Field`** class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field). You thus should rewrite your model to:

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

There is no need to add an `id` field. If you do not specify a primary key yourself, Django will make a field named `id` that is an [**`AutoField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField). You might want to make `img` an [**`ImageField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) instead, but that is another discussion.

Once you have constructed that model, you can run [**`manage.py makemigrations`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) to make migration files; and [**`manage.py migrate`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) to migrate your database and thus create the corresponding table(s).

In order to access the records of a model, you need to access a `Manager`, like the `.objects` Django will automatically attach to your model. Only `Manager`s and `QuerySet`s can `.filter(..)`, `.exclude(..)`, etc.

Another problem that you will encounter is that you need two consecutive underscores to use a field lookup, so `__icontains`, instead of `_icontains`.

Finally using `.distinct()` is useless here, since `desc` is a model field on the `Destination` model, and thus the filtering will not JOIN with outher tables.

You can thus implement this as:

```
    match = Destination.objects.filter(desc__icontains=query)
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```manager``` and ```QuerySet```. Will you please eloborate?

Comment: It is also giving me error after changes in match variable. ```type object 'Destination' has no attribute 'objects'```

Comment: @Ali: did you make `Destination` a model?

Comment: Yes this `class Destination:
 id : int
 desc : str
 img : str
 price :  int`

Comment: @Ali: can you please share your model definition? Edit your question.

Comment: I have added ```models.py``` in the above code. Check it.

Comment: @Ali: that is *not* a valid model definition, see update.

Comment: Whenever I ```makemigrations```, it gives me this error ```RuntimeError: Model class firstapp.models.Destination doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.```

Comment: @Ali: another error in your django setup: in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings, you should add a string with the name of your `firstapp`.

Comment: I have updated the code with installed apps. Check it what is the problem?

Comment: One question what you were talking about ``Manager``` and ```QuerySet```? I didn't understand that.

Comment: @Ali: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-attributes and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/